# How to extend AWS CDK with non AWS Resources during deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-alb, sumologic

I would like to automate setting up the collection of AWS Application Load Balancer logs using Sumo Logic as documented here:

https://help.sumologic.com/07Sumo-Logic-Apps/01Amazon_and_AWS/AWS_Elastic_Load_Balancer_-_Application/01_Collect_Logs_for_the_AWS_Elastic_Load_Balancer_Application_App

This involves creating a bucket, creating a Sumo Logic hosted collector with an S3 source, taking the URL of the collector source provided by Sumo Logic and then creating an SNS Topic with an HTTP subscription where the subscription URL is the one provided by the Sumo Logic source.

The issue with this is that the SumoLogic source URL is not known at synthesis time. The Bucket must be deployed, then the Sumlogic things created, then the SNS topic created.

As best I can figure, I will have to do this through separate invocations of CDK using separate stacks, which is slower.  One stack to create the bucket.  After deploying that stack, use the Sumo Logic api to create or affirm prior creation of the Sumo Logic hosted collector and source, another CDK deploy to create the SNS topic and HTTP subscription.

I was just wondering if anyone knew of a better way to do this, perhaps some sort of deploy time hook that could be used.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways(which I know of) in which you can automate the collection of AWS Application Load Balancer.

1. Using CloudFormation

- Sumo Logic have a [template](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-solution-templates/blob/master/aws-observability/apps/alb/alb_app.template.yaml) that creates the Collection process for AWS Application Load Balancer which is part of the AWS Observability Solution. You can fork the repository and can create your own CloudFormation template after removing resources you do not require.
- Sumo Logic also have a [Serverless Application](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home#/create/app?applicationId=arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:956882708938:applications/sumologic-s3-logging-auto-enable) which auto enable Access logging for existing and new (which are created after application installation) load balancer. Example [template](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-solution-templates/blob/master/aws-observability/apps/autoenable/auto_enable.template.yaml) which uses the application.

2. Using Terraform

- As mentioned by [Grzegorz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118587/grzegorz-oledzki), you can create a terraform script also.

Disclaimer: Currently employed by Sumo Logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Custom Resource SDK Call to trigger a lambda that does what you want.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsSdkCall.html

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is not a perfect answer as it suggests to use another tool, yet I believe it fulfills the needs expressed in the question)

How about using Terraform?

[`sumologic_s3_source` in Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/SumoLogic/sumologic/latest/docs/resources/s3_source) is able to create the source at Sumo **AND** output its URL for other uses within Terraform - e.g. to set up AWS resources.

The docs on this even mention URL being one of the returned values:

> url - The HTTP endpoint to use with SNS to notify Sumo Logic of new
> files.

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.